# NSMutableAttributedString subclass recognizes no selectors, even without modification?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring, foundation

I am trying to subclass `NSMutableAttributedString`, but I have found I am incapable of using it in any shape or form. Even as a freshly created subclass, it cannot be initialized:

The exception I receive is as follows:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ALCTMutableAttributedString initWithString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x16d21680'
```

It won't even work with a bare initialization call:

```
ALCTMutableAttributedString *newString = [[ALCTMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
```

And here is the bare contents of the Subclass:

**Header File:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ALCTMutableAttributedString : NSMutableAttributedString

@end
```

**Implementation File:**

```
#import "ALCTMutableAttributedString.h"

@implementation ALCTMutableAttributedString

@end
```

I'm pretty perplexed as to why this is disallowed, or not possible within my project. Might anyone know why?

**Extension:**

To demonstrate how I'm using the class, here is the header of the class in which I use it:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Foundation/Foundation.h"
#import "CXCommentLabel.h"
#import "ALCTMutableAttributedString.h"

@interface CXPodcastViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet CXCommentLabel *commentLabel;

@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *commentLabelHeightConstraint;

@property (nonatomic,weak)IBOutlet UIButton *resizeButton;

-(IBAction)resizeTheLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is how I call it: (.m file)

```
-(void)resizeTheLabel:(id)sender {
    // Crash here
    ALCTMutableAttributedString *newString = [[ALCTMutableAttributedString alloc]init];
    // Crash here ^
    [self.commentLabel setAttributedText:newString];
}
```

Comment: where is initialisation code??

Comment: @satheesh What do you mean? It's a Subclass of `NSMutableAttributedString`. It is initialized through it's superclass.

Comment: I think i have posted the expected solution, If not let me know

Comment: @satheesh No, it is useless. I'm not a fool, I know I need to import the header file. It still doesn't work.

Comment: @satheesh Sure, added the header, and relevant method within the class I use it in to this question. Check for yourself.

Comment: Better check this "https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-397934"

Subclassing of string using nsmutablestring is not possible

Comment: @satheesh Nice find, post that as your answer and I will choose it as correct when the time limit expires. Saw something similar to that earlier, but wasn't sure myself.

Comment: The link is related to `NSString`, not to `NSAttributedString`. `NSAttributedString` is not a subclass of `NSString`. However, subclassing Cocoa containers is not very convenient, so the documentation maybe valid in a way.

Comment: @Owatch I have edited the answer, please make it as correct if it solves your problem :)

Comment: @Owatch did you solve your problem ??? If not please let me know, i will try to find the solution,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-397934) ", In the apple documentation itself there s a section called "**Alternatives to Subclassing**" please check that too"

Subclassing of string using NSMutableAttributedString is not possible.

Alternative way to use the nsmutableattributed string is

```
-(void)resizeTheLabel:(id)sender {

  NSMutableAttributedString* attrStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"string" attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor]}];

  [self.commentLabel setAttributedText:newString];

}
```

Add the desired attribute to the dictionary and pass it as a parameter.
Happy Coding :)

Comment: Not very useful answer.  What would you suggest instead then?

Comment: @trojanfoe: 1) The questioner asked him to post the answer.  2) The questioner didn't explain why he wanted to subclass, so offering alternatives are not possible, even if the questioner wants any.

Comment: @trojanfoe In the apple documentation itself there s a section called "Alternatives to Subclassing" please check that

Comment: Perhaps add that to your answer.  It may help someone else in the future.

Comment: @Avi ok, I will add it :)

Comment: @satheesh So what is the alternative to subclassing that you'd suggest to the OP?

Comment: He has an NSMutable*Attributed*String, not an NSMutableString.

Comment: @satheesh It's not possible is the answer I guess. So, while not the solution I was hoping for, it is a solution in the end.